# preg_replace_callback regex issue, match with (.*?) returns array

Tags: php, regex

Given the string `{{esc}}"Content"{{/esc}} ... {{esc}}"More content"{{/esc}}` I would like to output `\"Content\" ... \"More content\"` e.g., I am trying to escape the quotes inside a string. (This is a contrived example, though, so an answer with something like 'just use this library to do it' would be unhelpful.)

Here is my current solution:

```
return preg_replace_callback(
  '/{{esc}}(.*?){{\/esc}}/', 
  function($m) {
    return str_replace('"', '\\"', $m[1]);
  },
  $text
);
```

As you can see, I need to say `$m[1]`, because a `print_r` reveals that `$m` looks like this:

```
Array 
(
    [0] => {{esc}}"Content"{{/esc}}
    [1] => "Content"
)
```

or, for the second match,

```
Array 
(
    [0] => {{esc}}"More content"{{/esc}}
    [1] => "More content"
)
```

My question is: *why does my regex cause `$m` to be an array?* Is there any way I can get the result of `$m[1]` as just a single variable `$m`?

Comment: This is documented behaviour, so the answer to your second question is "No".

Comment: Eh, it's in the [manual](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)?

Comment: Alas, I didn't see the bit about "parenthesized subexpressions." Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Jack, I answered my own question here since srain did not make this point clear: The second element of the array is the result captured by the parenthesized subexpression `(.*?)`, per the [PHP manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) Indeed, there does not appear to be a convenient way to extract the string matched by this subexpression otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The regex matches the string and puts the result into array. If match, the first index store the whole match string, the rest elements of the array are the string captured.

`preg_replace_callback()` acts like `preg_match()`:

```
 $result = array();
 preg_match('/{{esc}}(.*?){{\/esc}}/', $input_str, $result);

 // $result will be an array if match.
```